# How can we change user agent to "abcd" user agent in nginx whenever the user agent is a search engine like google or bing or yahoo or others?

Tags: nginx

We need to configure nginx so that we change the user agent if the request is coming from a search engine bot.

Will this config work? I do not want to break anything as it is a big live site. So any help will be greatly appreciated:

```
location / {
    if ($http_user_agent ~* /google/ ) {
    proxy_set_header        "User-Agent" "custom agent";
    proxy_pass              http://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Will changing the user agent in nginx create any unwanted issues with the site being served correctly to users as well as to search bots? We dont want our search results getting affected!! Nor do we want our users (browsers) to get affected.

**Just to explain why we need nginx to replace the user agent :**
The problem is that our server has been compromised and has some issue which will need time to resolve and hence we need to configure nginx urgently while we work out a long term solution.

Our server issue is that when it receives a request from user agent from a search engine it sends out the wrong content. But the server works well if the user agent is a normal browser other than a search engine.

So we wanted nginx to change the user agent to some custom name like "abcd" or to some valid browser user agent so that the search engine bots continue to receive the correct content.

Comment: There are a number of questions here, and it very much depends on what problem you are attempting to solve.

Comment: @RichardSmith the problem is that our server has some issue which will need time to resolve and hence we need to configure nginx urgently while we work out a long term solution. Our server issue is that when it receives a request from user agent from a search engine it sends out the wrong content. But the server works well if the user agent is a normal browser other than a search engine.

So we wanted nginx to change the user agent to some custom name like abcd or to soem valid browser user agent so that the search engine bots continue to receive the correct content.

Comment: I wrote a solution [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1006184/editing-nginx-http-headers/1006190#1006190) that might help.

Comment: @RichardSmith that solution entails writing outside the server block. Our hosting provider gives us permissions only to write within the server block. Will proxy_set_header not work in this case? I am unsure how to write the config correctly that will still take users browsers and the bots to the correct URL and things will function properly. Can you write the config lines that i need to add within the server block?
Like will i need to add proxy_pass and if I should use the proxy_set_header before the proxy_pass line or after that?

Comment: Will this work?

location / {
 if ($http_user_agent ~* \google\ ) {
    proxy_set_header        "User-Agent" "custom agent";
 proxy_pass              http://$host$request_uri;
}

Comment: If you want help with modifying the contents of the server block, you should edit your question and add the existing configuration.

Comment: @RichardSmith There is no existing configuration since our hosting provider gives us a blank ngnix config file and allows us to add location blocks. The other parts of the config like the server and even what is outside the server is not known to us. I have edited my question though.

Comment: I think this question may be off-topic as it seems to be specific to your hosting providers configuration portal, and you may be better off directing the question to them.